# Qt/C++ compiler string constant inlining

Tags: qt, c++11, gcc

I am currently in the process of optimizing my program for runtime memory usage. I have a bunch of locations where I am writing to a file and know the filepath already. Thats why I defined the literals as following:

```
const QString BLUE_LED = "/sys/class/leds/main:blue/trigger";
```

I can optimize this to be inlined better by doing this:

```
const char* const BLUE_LED = "/sys/class/leds/main:blue/trigger";
```

I am using this literal with the class QFile which has those constructors:

```
QFile(const QString &name, QObject *parent)
QFile(QObject *parent)
QFile(const QString &name)
```

Compiler flags I am using:

```
-c -pipe  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types
```

I suspect that the overall filesize will be going down but, the memory usage will increase for a fraction of a moment because in order to construct a QFile an intermediate QString will be constructed from the `const char* const`. Is this assumption correct? Is there a way to keep track of those impliciting constructions somehow, other then monitoring the programs memory usage?

Comment: Try QStringLiteral. Its internal data will be generated at compile time with all the field initialized.(use -std=c++0x, etc)

Comment: Is there additional benefit to using QLatin1StringLiteral, if I already know the encoding? Also is there implicit data copying when I supply a method foo(QString) with it?

Comment: Don't think so, all conversions, initializations, etc will happen at compile time, so you have like const object with all fields filled, data converted and  stored somethere in .rodata section. "const QString &name" will take reference of your your QStringLiteral with no cost. But if you do foo(QString) data will be copied and new QString object created(just the copy will be almost with no cost because of data stored in .rodata section). So const QStringLiteral is a good aproach

Comment: @Xplatforms I just performed the changes, and if I am not mistaken this increases memory usage by quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may wrap file name with QStringLiteral, but note that this takes more memory in .rodata, than string literal.
2. If you have to decrease memory usage at any cost, you may open file using

   ```
   FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
   ```

   and then open QFile using

   ```
   bool QFile::open(FILE *fh, OpenMode mode, FileHandleFlags handleFlags = DontCloseHandle)
   ```